# $x_i=x_{i-1}^2+a\pmod{N}$ with $N$ a composite number.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

$x_i=x_{i-1}^2+a\pmod{N}$, $N$ is an odd composite number, assume $N=p \cdot q$ with $p,q$ primes, $x_0=1$ then calculate $\gcd(x_i,N)$, for what $a$ the quadratic iterative function give one factor of $N$.

$N=4181=37 \cdot 113$, $a=4,7,2357$. The essential condition that $\gcd(x_i,N)\neq1$ maybe $a$ is a quadratic residue of $N$.

Comment: Can you rewrite this in short, simple declarative sentences so I have a chance of figuring out what you are asking?

Comment: This sounds similar to [Pollard's rho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm)...

Comment: @Gerry: An interrogative sentence would be useful too.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the Pollard rho method of factorization, as noted in the comments. Typically, the iteration generates only $C\sqrt p$ different residues modulo $p$ for some (fixed) constant $C$, so for any particular $a$ it's unlikely there will be an index $i$ with $\gcd(x_i,N)=p$.

To get $\gcd(x_i,N)=p$, $-a$ has to be a quadratic residue modulo $p$ (a necessary condition, but I don't expect it to be a sufficient condition).

Comment: If you calculate by yourself.the factor occurs Periodically,it's a  significant phenomenon.

Comment: Calculate *what* by myself?

Comment: Calculate $gcd(x_i,N)$

Comment: Are you paying by the word? Which $N$? Which $i$? Please make some attempt to *communicate*.

Comment: For $N=4181$, I get $i$ such that $\gcd(x_i,N)=37$ for $a=4,7,26,30,36,41,44,63,67,73,78,81,100,104,110,115,118,137,141,147,152,155,174,178,184,189,192$ and lots of other numbers. I get $\gcd(x_i,N)=113$ for $a=28,30,31,32,44,51,52,85,87,95,102,112,141,143,144,145,157,164,165,198,200$ and more. What am I supposed to make of these numbers?

Comment: maybe we can consider $f(x_i)=f(x_{i-1})\pmod{N}$eg.$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$